# Typescript: Enum from Interface keys

Tags: typescript, enums, interface

I have an interface:

```
interface ISomething {
  red: string;
  blue: string;
  green: string;
}
```

Is it possible to define Enum which will represent keys from the interface?

I would like to get result like this:

```
enum SomethingKeys {
   red = "red",
   blue= "blue",
   green= "green",
}
```

ps: I'm newbie in ts, sorry if the question isn't correct.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can do other way around by creating an object with keys of enum:

```
enum SomethingKeys {
   red = "red",
   blue= "blue",
   green= "green",
}
type ISomething= Record<SomethingKeys, string>
const a: ISomething = {
    [SomethingKeys.blue]: 'blue',
    [SomethingKeys.red]: 'red',
    [SomethingKeys.green]: 'green',
}
```

But I think what you really need is not enum but union type of keys, what you define by `keyof`. Consider:

```
interface ISomething {
  red: string;
  blue: string;
  green: string;
}
type Keys = keyof ISomething; // "red" | "blue" | "green"
```

And as you declare yourself as newbie, string literal unions are ok to be used. You don't need enums.

When you have `Keys` you can use them to create other types also

```
// new object with keys of the original one
type OtherTypeWithTheSameKeys = Record<Keys, number> // type with keys of type Keys
const a: OtherTypeWithTheSameKeys = {
  blue: 1,
  green: 2,
  red: 3
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the ansver. Is it possible to create an object with properties from interface keys?

Comment: Yes, added you a sample

Comment: Thank you, could you please advise, it is possible to define such object automaticaly in some function?